# Printing user defined types in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml, user-defined-types

I am defining a new type which is basically a string. How to print the value ?

```
# type mytp = Mytp of string;;
type mytp = Mytp of string
# let x = Mytp "Hello Ocaml";;
val x : mytp = Mytp "Hello Ocaml"
# print_endline x;;
Error: This expression has type mytp but an expression was expected of type
         string
#
```

This question already has answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380755/ocaml-get-values-type-name).
There is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518752/is-there-a-way-to-print-user-defined-datatypes-in-ocaml) similar to this, which I had went through before asking the question, however I was not clear (maybe because I am a complete newbie. Other newbies might face similar confusion.) how to solve the problem from the accepted answer.

Comment: the accepted answer didn't mention the syntactic construct needed.

Comment: There is no syntactic construct specifically needed to print user-defined types. There is a syntactic construct needed to deconstruct a variant in order to get data out of it, but that isn't the question you asked. That is a different question.

Comment: Ocaml newbie here! What I meant by syntactic construct is pattern matching (see the conversation in the accepted answer of this question). The accepted answer of the other question doesn't talk about pattern matching and I was not clear how to solve the problem reading that answer.  Anyways, is there anything that I should do now?

Comment: Well, the idea behind Stack Overflow is to be a searchable knowledge base of questions and answers to specific programming problems. A better question is one that is more specific and more "searchable", which is intentionally a bit of a fuzzy term since search algorithms are complex and ever-changing. In your case, since "how to print" has already been answered (and you now reference that, which is good), the core of your question is really just how to get data out of a variant, which is so fundamental that it really belongs in a tutorial rather than in a Q&A format, and hence off-topic anyway

Comment: So you might as well just leave it as it is, but I hope you take it as an opportunity to learn (about asking and problem solving). You could probably have figured this out on your own by following the advice in the help center about creating a [mcve] in order to ask a good question, which has the additional benefit of helping you understand the problem. Doing so is on its own often enough to see that the solution is trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of print_endline is `string -> unit`. So you can't pass a value of type mytp.

You can write a function to print a value of type mytp:

```
let print_mytp (Mytp s) = print_endline s
```

You can write a function to convert mytp to string:

```
let string_of_mytp (Mytp s) = s
```

Then you can print like so:

```
print_endline (string_of_mytp x)
```

OCaml will not allow you to use mytp where string is expected, or vice versa. This is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: Ocaml newbie here. I understood that type-mismatch issue. What I didnt know was the construct (MyType innertype). What is the name of this construct?

Also, thanks for the prompt answer.

Comment: `(MyType innertype)` is a pattern. For things like `mytp` you access the contained values by pattern matching.